# Does the UK have any constraint on work permit for previous Chinese work permit holders?

Tags: visas, uk, europe, china, work

Is it true that people (from other 3rd world countries)who have `previously worked in China`(with Chinese work permit) are `not allowed to work in the UK` (`work permit` for UK becomes `troublesome or are not given`)?

I work in a IT firm in India and I have heard this recently from one of my friends which made me curious. Any inputs on this is highly appreciated!

Comment: It's gossip and rumour.  Wholly unsubstantiated.

Comment: This question is better suited for Skeptics.StackExchange.Com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unsubstantiated. I worked in the UK for several years (IT worker) and met a few people who had worked in China (teaching English, among other things) and they had zero issues getting visas.

It's one of those cases where you hear stories about visas (you hear a LOT from expats, it's just one of those things) and the rule is - until you see it written on an official site, don't believe it.

It's possible that some rumours have arisen from Britain [still having some restrictions on Chinese investors](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/china-business/10898327/China-warns-that-visa-restrictions-are-eroding-UKs-strength.html).

Statements like this (quote from article linked):

> Mr Liu said that prominent Chinese businessmen are still being
>   rejected when they apply for visas to come to the UK.
>
> He said that many were rejected and unable to attend a recent business
>   leaders’ summit but that he did not know the “real reason” their visa
>   applications were turned down.

also don't help matters.  If he actually asked them, he could find out why and it could be for all sorts of reasons - incorrect applications, failure to provide evidence of actual business transactions, failure to show funds, exit tickets etc, but instead, more unsubstantiated statements.

Comment: Hi Mark! Thank you very much for your post. Appreciate it. :)

Comment: +1 for taking the extra time to nail this laughable rumour  down with a citation.  You get the 'Snopes Badge'